# Probability of i.i.d random variables not being equal to each other

Tags: probability, combinatorics, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m$ be i.i.d random variables uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,2, \dots, n\}$. What is $\mathbb{P}(X_1\neq X_2 \neq \dots \neq X_m)$?

Edit: n > m

Comment: When you write $X_1\neq X_2\neq\dots X_m$, do you mean exactly that, or do you want them to be pairwise distinct? $X_1\neq X_2\neq X_3$ allows $X_1 =X_3$, is that what you want?

Comment: @Reveillark I mean that none of them equals the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For $m>n$, it's just zero because you can't pick $m> n$ distincts numbers out of a set of cardinal n.
- For $m\le n$, notice that

  1. you have $n$ choice for $X_1$,
  2. but then there are $n-1$ choices left for $X_2$,
  3. then $n-2$ choices left for $X_3$,
  4. ...
  5. finally, $n-m+1$ choices left for $X_m$

Putting everything together, the probabilty we're looking for is : $\frac{n}{n}\times\frac{n-1}{n}\times\frac{n-2}{n}...\times\frac{n-m+1}{n}=\frac{n!}{n^m (n-m)!}$

Comment: The end result should be $\frac{n!}{n^m(n-m)!}$

Comment: @DanielMathias, You're right, my bad !

Answer (score 2):

If $m>n$; then the answer is $0$, because you'd have to choose $m$ different numbers out of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, which is obviously impossible.

If $n\ge m$, then you need to choose, with order, $m$ many numbers out of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to act as values of $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Do you see how to do this?